# Vuetify Snackbar: click does not invoke my function

Tags: vuetify.js

How can I detect if a user clicks anywhere on the snackbar? (not on the close icon)

`@click` doesnt work.

```
  <v-snackbar
    v-model="active"
    ...
    @click="dismiss" <-- doesnt invoke functon
  >
  ...
  </v-snackbar>
```

---

```
export default class Toast extends Vue {
  ...
  dismiss(): void {
    console.log('dismiss', this.$props); // <-- not seeing this
    if (this.$props.dismissable) {
      this.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Vuetify documentation says,

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-snackbar/#events

There is no "click" event emitted by `v-snackbar` component.

However, you can still use the `native` modifier on your listener :

```
<v-snackbar
    v-model="active"
    @click.native="dismiss"
>
</v-snackbar>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Did forget about the native.

Comment: It seems this answer is not up to date?